# How networks with high largest eigenvalues are more robust?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spectral-sequences

In the literature, it sometimes indicates that network with high value of largest eigenvalue (either adjacency matrix or its Laplacian counterpart) are more robust. Robustness here is relevant to link/node removals. However, these statements are usually NOT accompanied with references.

I am looking for some explanation on why is this so? Or pointers to some work that investigate/explain this.